# Как лучше сделать загрузку фото?

Tags: android, java

Есть идея - стараюсь реализовать в процессе обучения - принцип приложения тот же, что и в инстаграме, только вот не могу придумать, как или куда сделать загрузку фото: допустим, у меня есть приложение, другие фоткают, и фото загружается только в мой смартфон или на сервер обмена? 
Прощу прощения за абстрактный вопрос, новичок же. )

Comment: На сервер, естественно.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы фото видели только вы, ваш смартфон.
Если фото должно быть доступно для вас и других пользователей, тогда веб-сервер.